# getJSON - displaying the data from JSON URL feed

Tags: javascript, html, json, getjson

I have a JSON URL - http://j.mp/1l1amIY

I am using JQuery and getJSON.

```
$.getJSON('URL OF JSON', function(data) {

});
```

How do I display all records one after each other - as HTML?

How do I display the 1st record only - as HTML?

How do I display a specific record based on an IF then ELSE condition?

I can find variables being sent to consoles in online tutorials but nothing when it comes to displaying the records and running conditions.

Answer (score 0):

please use this example as reference.

```
$('#content').html(response.posts[0].content);

http://jsfiddle.net/mdawaffe/hLWdH/
```

Should be simple to write one.